# Why does time(time_t *) function both return and set the by-ref?

Tags: c, time, libc

I've always been curious, why does the `time(time_t *)` function both return a `time_t`, and set the time to the passed in pointer?

Example of returning the time:

```
time_t myTime = time(NULL);
printf("The time is now %s", ctime(&myTime));
```

Example of setting the value to the pointer:

```
time_t myTime;
time(&myTime);
printf("The time is now %s", ctime(&myTime));
```

I originally thought there would be a performance gain by writing to the memory instead of returning, but if it has to do both, doesn't that just make it slower?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's no real benefit in the way it's currently defined.

I suspect that when the `time()` function was first defined, it used a type that could not be returned from a function.  Very early C implementations didn't have `long int` and were not able to return structures from functions.  On a system with 16-bit ints, the only way to represent a time would be as a structure or as an array; 16 bits worth of seconds is less than a day.

*UPDATE: My speculation is confirmed, see below.*

So early implementations of `time()` might have been used something like this (speculation):

```
time_t now;
time(&now);    /* sets now.time_high, now.time_low */
```

or perhaps:

```
int now[2];
time_t(now);    /* sets now[0], now[1] */
```

When later C implementations added longer integers and the ability to return structures by value, the ability to return a `time_t` value from the `time()` function was added, but the old functionality was kept to avoid breaking existing code.

I think that if `time()` were being defined today, it would look more like this:

```
time_t time(void);
```

I haven't been able to confirm that old implementations of the `time()` function worked this way (try Googling "time"!), but it makes sense given the history of the language.

If you pass a null pointer to the `time()` function, it returns the current time without also storing it in a variable; this avoids some of the performance penalty:

```
time_t now = time(NULL);
```

**UPDATE**

Early UNIX sources are available in https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo

Checking out the `Research-V6` git tag, the man page for the `time()` system call is in `usr/doc/man/man2/time.2`. It's written in an obsolete form of *roff, but here's my attempt at formatting it. (The implementation, written in PDP-11 assembly and callable from C, is in `usr/source/s2/time.s`.)

C didn't have `void` functions at that time. Functions without a declared return type would return `int` by default. It's not clear to me what the `time` function would return, but my guess is that it would be the high-order 16-bit word of the 32-bit value. As of the date on the man page, that would have been about 1730, in units of 2<sup>16</sup> seconds (18h12m16s). Correctly written C code would not have attempted to use the return value.

### TIME 8/5/73

#### NAME

time - get date and time

#### SYNOPSIS

```
(time = 13.)
sys time

time(tvec)
int tvec[2]
```

#### DESCRIPTION

*Time* returns returns the time since 00:00:00 GMT, Jan. 1, 1970, measured
in seconds.  From *as*, the high order word is in the r0 register and
the low order is in r1.  From C, the user-supplied vector is filled in.

#### SEE ALSO

date (I), stime (II), ctime (III)

Comment: That sounds plausible. I was expecting the performance penalty to go the other way. It's avoided if you pass a NULL, but if you call it with a pointer and ignore the return result, it still has to shove the time into the return register. Sometimes I forget that C is nearly twice as old as I am. :)

Comment: *Sometimes I forget that C is nearly twice as old as I am.* -- Thanks for making me feel old! 8-)}

Comment: Thank you for coming and updating this, years later!

Answer (score 7):

It allows you to nest a call to `time()` within another expression, instead of doing it in a separate statement:

```
time_t x = time(&now) + more_time;
```

When the above statement finishes, `now` should contain the current time, and `x` should contain the current time plus some value.

`strcpy` falls in the same case because it returns the same `char *` pointer that has been passed as its destination, so nesting it is possible as well:

```
printf("Copied string is %s", strcpy(dst, src));
```

Comment: If `time()` took no arguments, that could just as easily be done by nesting an assignment: `time_t x = (now=time())` + more_time;`

Comment: While I agree with Keith, this answer is the first I've seen to provide a potential convenient usage for `time`'s odd signature...

Comment: I think in both cases it'd be better to use two lines for readability sake. It probably compiles down to the same thing either way.