# Why the UNIX time(2) system call is designed like that?

Tags: unix, pass-by-reference, system-calls

The UNIX time(2) system call, `time_t time(time_t *t);`, returns the current time in two ways: return value and return-by-reference. What's the rational for this redundancy? Why not just define it `time_t time(void);`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does time(time\_t \*) function both return and set the by-ref?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944771/why-does-timetime-t-function-both-return-and-set-the-by-ref)

Comment: My bad. Didn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ancient history, but it is probably related to the time when a long was simulated by two 16-bit `int` values in tandem.  Otherwise, there's no real obvious reason.  Interestingly, the UNIX™ 7th Edition Manual documents `time` as obsolete:

> **NAME**
>
> time, ftime – get date and time
>
> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> `long time(0)`
>   `long time(tloc)`
>   `long *tloc;`
>
> `#include <sys/types.h>`
>   `#include <sys/timeb.h>`
>   `ftime(tp)`
>   `struct timeb *tp;`
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> Time returns the time since 00:00:00 GMT, Jan. 1, 1970, measured in seconds.
>   If *tloc* is nonnull, the return value is also stored in the place to which *tloc* points.
>   The ftime entry fills in a structure pointed to by its argument, as defined by `<sys/timeb.h>`:
>
> ```
> /*
> * Structure returned by ftime system call
> */
> struct timeb
> {
> time_t time;
> unsigned short millitm;
> short timezone;
> short dstflag;
> };
> ```
>
> The structure contains the time since the epoch in seconds, up to 1000 milliseconds of more-precise
>   interval, the local timezone (measured in minutes of time westward from Greenwich), and a flag that, if
>   nonzero, indicates that Daylight Saving time applies locally during the appropriate part of the year.
>
> **SEE ALSO**
>
> date(1), stime(2), ctime(3)
>
> **ASSEMBLER**
>
> ```
> (ftime = 35.)
> sys ftime; bufptr
>
> (time = 13.; obsolete call)
> sys time
> (time since 1970 in r0-r1)
> ```

Note the designation 'obsolete call', and note that the return value was in two (16-bit) registers, *r0* and *r1*.