# Is there a reason why C++ does not overload time function so we do not need to write NULL?

Tags: c++, std

This is not about me being lazy to write

```
auto t = time(nullptr);
```

instead of hypothetical

```
auto t = time();
```

I am mostly interested if this is possible, and if it is(AFAIK it is easily implementable since C++ supports function overloading) why it has not been done.

I know obvious answers like: use `<chrono>`, nobody wrote proposal, but I wonder if there is a different reason.

My best guess is that nobody wanted to mess with C library functions.

P.S. I understand that some might want to close this question as too vague, but I feel that it is possible to give relatively objective answer to this question.

Comment: A deeper question is "why does `time_t time(time_t*)` even take that pointer parameter at all?".

Comment: Is it worth it? `time(nullptr)` Vs `time()` - who cares? How often do you call that function in any real-life program? Once? Twice? It simply doesn't matter.

Comment: It's probably inherited from C, which has no function overloading, then kept for compatibility and now probably no one cares anymore, because C++ has [std::chrono](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono) now. But it's impossible to say for sure.

Comment: C does not allow overloads and C++ did not want std::time from <ctime> to have different interface from time from <time.h> since both are valid in C++.

Comment: You can simply write a function that calls that function so yes, it can be done. But it is part of the inherited `C` library which the `C++` standard likes to avoid making too many changes to.

Comment: Here's my (largely speculative) answer about why `time()` both takes a pointer argument and returns a value: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9945669/827263

Comment: You can fix this yourself: `inline time_t goodtime() {return ::time(nullptr);}`

Comment: I've updated [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9945669/827263) I linked to above, confirming my hypothesis by looking at old (early 1970s) UNIX sources.

Comment: If you dig into the C library, you'll see other functions that accept a pointer, only to return it (either returning the pointer itself, or a value).   The most commonly known example are string functions (`strcpy()`, `strcat()`) which return their first argument to permit chaining of function calls in a single statement e.g. `strcat(a, strcat(b, strcpy(d, "Hello")))` rather forcing writing of three distinct statements.    There was considerable advocacy (reflected in some old textbooks) that the single-statement form was "cleaner" than the multi-statement form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple answer is that `time(time_t)` is “owned” by C rather than by C++: the standard C++ committee doesn’t interfere with the C library unless there are reasons why it is necessary. With C++ you should get a better interface using `<chrono>` functions.

Also: I don’t think there was a proposal to overload this function. Without a proposal nothing is going to happen and I doubt anybody sufficiently eager to write such a proposal and get it through the process.

Comment: Also difference between time and std::time would cause lot of confused Stack Overflow posts of noobs who write using namespace std, as first thing in their code. So I'm against such proposal.

Comment: *“owned” by C* This is a non-issue (see std::abs for example).

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.: well, the function signature was inherited and nobody felt a need to mess with it. Sure, the C++ committee could choose to overload it but unlike other functions there isn’t any big need. `abs()` was overloaded to avoid accidental conversions and to avoid the need to call the respect `float` or `long double` versions. There aren’t any traps with `time()`.